# Make what's already been drawn transparent?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, transparency

I'm finishing the last of a Connect 4 game. I wanted to have the tile actually drop down instead of just appearing in the slot, but there's a z-ordering problem.

To draw my scene, I first draw a rectangle for the board, and then cut out holes in it by painting over it with the background colour. The problem is that there's no room for the tile. I've tried drawing the tile before anything else. It drops down, but you can't see it behind the holes, since they're drawn in solid black over solid yellow over my tile. I can't draw it after the black, but before the yellow either, because the yellow is drawn first. Here's a pretty picture:

[image: The playing board.]

I have a few possibilities for a solution, but problems with each:

1. Use a bitmap of the board with the holes already cut out.

   - I could draw the tiles, and then the oddly-shaped frame with a transparency key.
   - Would `StretchBlt` or something similar actually stretch the board to look the same on different resolutions, including different aspect ratios (by same I mean scale horizontally and vertically as to have the same ratios every time)? Making reference to the picture, it fits the window like this no matter what the resolution.
2. Go through pixel by pixel and check what to draw.

   - It's simple, but wouldn't it be very slow? I've heard going through each pixel might not be, but haven't really verified it anywhere.
3. (The one I think would work best) - Draw the board, but instead of black holes on top, make the board transparent in those areas instead.

   - It's the least amount of work, and should ok efficiency-wise, but how would I even do this?

Are any of these solutions (especially the third) plausible? Is there an easy way to solve this z-order problem otherwise?

Comment: Oh, for some reason I read this as an OpenGL question. Nevermind then.

Comment: @Pubby, I see. I've used them in Direct3D, so I know where you're coming from.

Comment: I think the fast way to do approach #2 would be to supply a monochrome mask bitmap to specify which pixels from your source bitmap should actually be copied to your destination bitmap.  (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145047(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: As an aside, that image is harsg on the eyes (and aren't the traditional tile colors red and black as well?). I can't tell if it's the color scheme (try a grey or greyish-blue background, or maybe dulling the yellow) or the actual pattern (try adding decorations or adjusting the spacing) that's the problem.

Comment: @Hurkyl, The version I had when I was little was red+blue ;) Apart from that, I initially had that feeling as well, but it's a lot better than what it used to look like. I can play around with it, but it's just for part of an English presentation, so I'm not overly worried about everything being perfect (It's already adding grammar questions in order to make your move!!!). The black background was mostly from the possibility of adding 3D graphics/animations. It works well there. I realize this is a huge problem for any game that I would publish/distribute, though. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the most "correct" way (not necessarily the best way) would be to fill a shape that is your rectangle with holes in it, rather than adding the holes later.

If you're using GDI or GDI+, you can do this by creating a path with the rectangle and all of the circles in it, then filling that path.

To do this in gdi32, call BeginPath, use the Rectangle and Ellipse functions to add the shapes to the path, and call EndPath to finish it. Use SetPolyFillMode to set the HDC to ALTERNATE mode. Select the appropriate brush in your HDC, and call FillPath.

In GDI+, construct a path in alternate mode, add your shapes with GraphicsPath::AddRectangle and GraphicsPath::AddEllipse, and fill it with Graphics::FillPath.

(You could do this with winding mode instead of alternate, but then you'd have to be careful about whether the lines making the shapes in your path are clockwise or counterclockwise.)

Comment: Well, it took me a while, but I finally got around to trying it, and it works wonderfully. Thanks a lot!